# Some clients cannot get their IP after updating Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ip

- client using Chrome version 75.0.3770.100 64bit:some can  provide valid IP, some don't(see below example for valid or invalid)

What I have try:
(p.s. x are number below)
1. Not valid IP provided client: Uninstall Chrome -> Update to older version: 71.0.3578.80 64bit
(Got valid Ip e.g. 1x2.1x.2.x1)

2. Not valid IP provided client: Uninstall Chrome -> Update to older version -> Update back to latest version: 75.0.3770.100 64bit -> Restart computer (Not work, got invalid ip: candidate:7x3x0x8x0 1 udp 21x3x3x1x1 31xcxece-ax6f-x3f2-abx9-f1f4fb9x5x6x.local 4xx1x typ host generation 0 ufrag Bkiq network-cost 999 )

The code:

```
    //compatibility for firefox and chrome
    var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var pc = new myPeerConnection({
        iceServers: []
    }),
    noop = function() {},
    localIPs = {},
    ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
    key;

    function iterateIP(ip) {
        if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
        localIPs[ip] = true;
    }

     //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createDataChannel("");

    // create offer and set local description
    pc.createOffer().then(function(sdp) {
        sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
            if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
            line.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
        });

        pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
    }).catch(function(reason) {
        // An error occurred, so handle the failure to connect
    });

    //listen for candidate events
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) {
        return ice.candidate.candidate; // comment below, as it will return nothing as the ip does not match the ipRegex
        // if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
        // ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
    // };
}

// Usage

getUserIP(function(ip){
    alert("Got IP! :" + ip);
});
```

I hope even updated to the latest version of chrome(75.0.3770.100 64bit) all customers can provide valid ip

Answer (score 1):

Use stun/turn server ips/domains in `iceServers` configuration instead of empty, e.g. `{ "iceServers": [ { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' } ] }`. Stun/turn servers are necessary when clients are on a different network.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround solution that let the user ip can send back to server after updating the latest chrome:

1. User go chrome://flags
2. search 'Anonymize local IPs exposed by WebRTC.' which conceal local IP addresses with mDNS hostnames. – Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS
3. disable it

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, it's expected as you won't be able to obtain addresses that way in the future.

WebRTC hosts candidates will now be anonymized using random mDNS hostnames to prevent websites from diverting WebRTC to snoop on local IPv4 addresses. The behavior is gradually enabled for all Chrome users. It's also being implemented in Firefox.

Here are the corresponding bugs for [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail_ezt?id=333752) and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1544770), and the current [IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-mdns-ice-candidates-03) for WebRTC mDNS candidates.